# How to use an async function in a move || closure?

Tags: rust

I use a tray to add some context menu in windows's tray. (https://docs.rs/tray-item/0.7.0/tray_item/struct.TrayItem.html).

the package give me an example to handle menu click event like this:

```
tray.add_menu_item("CLICK ME", move || handle_click()).unwrap();
```

The problem is that my function I want to run, `handle_click()` is an async function:

```
// this function does something and returns nothing
// must use async since some_function() is async
pub async fn handle_click() {
    match some_function().await {
        Ok(_) => println!("Click is happening"),
        Err(_) => println!("Error.... >.<),
    };
}
```

I think this will be easy but I cant figure it out.
If I use

```
tray.add_menu_item("CLICK ME", async move || handle_click()).unwrap();
```

this gives an error:

```
   --> src\main.rs:68:42
    |
68  |     tray.add_menu_item("CLICK ME", async move || handle_click())
    |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ------------------ the found `async` closure body
    |                                          |
    |                                          expected `()`, found opaque type
```

After modifying to this:

```
tray.add_menu_item("CLICK ME",, move || {
    println!("hello world 1!");
    async {
        println!("hello worold 2!");
        test_printer_zpl().await;
    };
})
.unwrap();
```

It compiles, but anything inside `async {}` block can't run. Why is that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Async closures are not stable in rust today. You must write closure that returns a async block.

```rust
tray.add_menu_item("CLICK ME", move || {
    async { handle_click().await };
})
.unwrap();
```

EDIT. Addressing your new question. "Documentation is lacking", so I cannot be sure, but it seems that `add_menu_iterm` doesn't accept async functions. So your `Future` (the async block) is returned, but not `.await`ed, so it does nothing. If you want to use asynchronous code in sync context you must manually spin up an executor. You can try for example `tokio`'s [block_on](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Runtime.html#method.block_on)

```rust
tray.add_menu_item("CLICK ME", move || {
    let rt = tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap();
    rt.block_on(handle_click());
})
.unwrap();
```

Comment: wait... the code can be compiled but the `handle_click` function doesn't run at all.

Comment: @DennyHiu Added new answer.